# How to display SRTM15 PLUS netcdf grid?

Tags: netcdf, srtm, display

I'm trying to display SRTM15PLUS netcdf grid (topo15.grd) with different software (QGIS, ArcGIS, IDV) but I always get the same messed up result.
Any suggestions?
SRTM15PLUS grid is available here: ftp://topex.ucsd.edu/pub/srtm15_plus/
[image: topo15 grid display]

Comment: For fun, I was going to try and test this until I saw the filesize: **13.9** GB.

Comment: I recommend focusing on one GIS software at a time and work through that before jumping to the next.

Comment: yes, unfortunately there is no way to download a subset of SRTM15PLUS global grid from http://topex.ucsd.edu/WWW_html/srtm30_plus.html

Comment: Looks like a tiling screwup or potentially overviews, you could try converting the file or just a subset.  Can you post the output of gdalinfo on the file? Fwiw pretty sure I downloaded srtm tiles last week, but yours must be merged with bathy?

Comment: The downloaded file renders fine here, so it seems to be a broken download on your side. I suggest to download again (although it takes hours...).

Comment: Yes new downloaded file is fine here too now, thanks

Comment: Yes SRTM15plus is ground elevation + bathymetry